# infinity loading when try to scrap title article with cheerio

Tags: express, cheerio

infinity loading when try to scrap title article
i was trying to scrap title articles with cheerio in node js but i could not make it happen
infinity loading in google chrome and no content . here is my controller.js file that i trying to use cheerio to scrap title articles with cheerio and show handlesbars view engine
but view engie is working and everything is fine . but for scrap infinity loading in chrome with no error
classname that i use for this website is .c-entry-box--compact__title
maybe i am wrong . but i can not figure out

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var path = require("path");

var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var Comment = require("../models/Comment.js");
var Article = require("../models/Article.js");

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("/articles");
});

router.get("/scrape", function(req, res) {
  request("http://www.theverge.com", function(error, response, html) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var titlesArray = [];

    $(".c-entry-box--compact__title").each(function(i, element) {
      var result = {};

      result.title = $(this)
        .children("a")
        .text();
      result.link = $(this)
        .children("a")
        .attr("href");

      if (result.title !== "" && result.link !== "") {
        if (titlesArray.indexOf(result.title) == -1) {
          titlesArray.push(result.title);

          Article.count({ title: result.title }, function(err, test) {
            if (test === 0) {
              var entry = new Article(result);

              entry.save(function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log(doc);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Article already exists.");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Not saved to DB, missing data");
      }
    });
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});
router.get("/articles", function(req, res) {
  Article.find()
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .exec(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        var artcl = { article: doc };
        res.render("index", artcl);
      }
    });
});

router.get("/articles-json", function(req, res) {
  Article.find({}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(doc);
    }
  });
});

router.get("/clearAll", function(req, res) {
  Article.remove({}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("removed all articles");
    }
  });
  res.redirect("/articles-json");
});

router.get("/readArticle/:id", function(req, res) {
  var articleId = req.params.id;
  var hbsObj = {
    article: [],
    body: []
  };

  Article.findOne({ _id: articleId })
    .populate("comment")
    .exec(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
      } else {
        hbsObj.article = doc;
        var link = doc.link;
        request(link, function(error, response, html) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(html);

          $(".l-col__main").each(function(i, element) {
            hbsObj.body = $(this)
              .children(".c-entry-content")
              .children("p")
              .text();

            res.render("article", hbsObj);
            return false;
          });
        });
      }
    });
});
router.post("/comment/:id", function(req, res) {
  var user = req.body.name;
  var content = req.body.comment;
  var articleId = req.params.id;

  var commentObj = {
    name: user,
    body: content
  };

  var newComment = new Comment(commentObj);

  newComment.save(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(doc._id);
      console.log(articleId);

      Article.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        { $push: { comment: doc._id } },
        { new: true }
      ).exec(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.redirect("/readArticle/" + articleId);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Cheerio doesn't execute JS, so I'd imagine infinity loaders won't be scrapable. Maybe try Puppeteer?

Comment: ok  i will try puppeteer .

Answer (score 0):

The `http://www.theverge.com` Add content dynamically by scrolling.

This is example how to get the title by `puppeteer`

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const getTitle = async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await page.goto('https://www.theverge.com');

        await page.setViewport({
            width:1920,
            height:1080
        });
        // scroll down end of page
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            window.scrollTo(0, window.document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }), // (0 network connections for 500ms)
        // get the title
        titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const textSelector = 'div.inline.pr-4.font-bold'
            texts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(textSelector), row => row.innerText.trim() );
            return texts;
        });
        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(titles);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

getTitle()
    .then((titles) => {
        console.log(titles);    // first news search
    })
```

This is result

```
[
  'Is an upgraded M2 Ultra enough for a new Mac Pro and the Mac Studio?',
  'Here’s the official trailer for Christopher Nolan’s next IMAX-filmed epic, Oppenheimer.',
  'Sam Bankman-Fried’s ready to surrender himself to the US for extradition.',
  'Who knew the thumb drive had such a contentious origin story?',
  'But how many pebbles do you have in a jar?',
  'This way for The Way of Water.',
  'Netflix is taking Blockbuster behind the woodshed again.',
  'I can’t escape the year-end wrap-ups.',
  'The clock’s ticking if you want to get your gifts on time.',
  'Want solar panels on your California home? Now might be the time.',
  'Twitter Spaces has returned.',
  'Apple’s facing another accusation of breaking labor laws.',
  'Every game should have this feature.',
  'Google’s working on simplifying smart home control on the wrist.',
  'Apple could open up iOS, and the feds finally make a case against SBF.',
  'I’m not the first, and I won’t be the last... but I do feel early.',
  'For what it’s worth, Avatar: The Way of Water’s a good looking movie.',
  'You may not want to upgrade to Apple’s new Home architecture.'
]
```